# How to run Angular CLI commands from code

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics

is there a way to run ng g component from code - something like on button click from UI need to run this command and component should be created.

Purpose : I have created Angular custom schematic which is used as dependency in angular application. If i run **ng g schematic:home** from angular application terminal it will call a Rule to create home component - but instead of running **ng g schematic:home** in terminal need to call schematic from angular application programmatically(from code)

Comment: web applications don't have read/write access to your machine , its a security threat... you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create components from any events.

Comment: in Node.js exec("npm ---") is available  to run npm command from code right..? does angular not supprot this kind of execution

Comment: I have no idea about it, I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: I have added what exactly i am trying to achieve and updated my question. please have a look